# How to handle Arabic characters on Solr

Tags: search, solr, arabic

I'm trying to make my site ignore some Arabic characters ex("ه"،"ة") during the search. when user search for word end with "ة" like "مدينة" it brings only word end with that character "ة", it's supposed to bring also the words ends with "ه" like "مدينه".

these characters are the same in the Arabic language so the search result shouldn't be different, but my site produce different results

what I try on my schema_extra_types.xml

```
<fieldType name="text_ar" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <charFilter class="solr.MappingCharFilterFactory" mapping="accents_ar.txt"/>
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords_ar.txt"/>
    <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterGraphFilterFactory" catenateNumbers="1" generateNumberParts="1" protected="protwords_ar.txt" splitOnCaseChange="0" generateWordParts="1" preserveOriginal="1" catenateAll="0" catenateWords="1"/>
    <filter class="solr.LengthFilterFactory" min="2" max="100"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory" language="Arabic" protected="protwords_ar.txt"/>
    <filter class="solr.NGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="3" maxGramSize="25" />
    <filter class="solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory" /> 
    <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <charFilter class="solr.MappingCharFilterFactory" mapping="accents_ar.txt"/>
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.SynonymGraphFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms_ar.txt" expand="true" ignoreCase="true"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords_ar.txt"/>
    <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterGraphFilterFactory" catenateNumbers="0" generateNumberParts="1" protected="protwords_ar.txt" splitOnCaseChange="0" generateWordParts="1" preserveOriginal="1" catenateAll="0" catenateWords="0"/>
    <filter class="solr.LengthFilterFactory" min="2" max="100"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory" language="Arabic" protected="protwords_ar.txt"/>
    <filter class="solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory" /> 
    <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

but the accents_ar.txt empty when I download the config folder from drupal admin interface,and where I can find an example of accents_ar.txt to use on my site? or there is another filter class to handle these kind of issues?